# java datetime difference given a start date

Tags: java, datetime, jodatime, date-difference

I have a time variable `startDate`:

```
startDate = 2018-01-01 00:00:40.554
```

And I want to calculate `endDay` which is 24 hours from the `startDate`, and `endHour` which is 60 minutes from the `startDate`.

```
dayDiff = Days.daysBetween(startDate.toLocalDate(), 24hours.toLocalDate()).getDays()
```

So basically:

```
startDate + 1day = endDay
startDate + 60mins = endHour
```

Comment: I'm finding it very difficult to understand your question - your description sounds like you want to just compute `endDay`, but your sample *uses* `endDay`. Please take some time to make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: What you are look for is "how to add a time to a date in java?". Once you will find a quick guide, you should find the answer pretty fast since you need a dqte like "startDate + 1day" and "startDate + 1hour". But your question is presenting the opposite "how to get the difference between two dates".

Comment: Yes..thats exactly what I meant

Comment: @adu have you simply consulted the javadoc of the classes you're using? The answer is in there, and it's pretty obvious. http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add one day into Joda-Time DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461361/add-one-day-into-joda-time-datetime)

Comment: Also related: [Problem adding minutes with plusMinutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540144/problem-adding-minutes-with-plusminutes).

Comment: FYI, the [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using Joda-Time, because you used `Days.daysBetween` and I don't know another API with such class and method.

Anyway, `Days.daysBetween` calculates the **difference** between 2 date/times (a number that represents how many days there are between those dates), but what you really need is to **add a duration** (1 day or 1 hour) to a date.

Assuming that `startDate` is a [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html), you can do:

```
DateTime endDay = startDate.plusHours(24);
DateTime endHour = startDate.plusMinutes(60);
```

If the type of `startDate` is another one (such as `LocalDateTime`), don't worry, all these core classes have similar methods as well.

I called `plusHours(24)`, but I could also use `plusDays(1)`. Just remind that, as noted in the comments, adding 1 day is not always the same as adding 24 hours, [due to Daylight Saving Time issues](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/transition.html) (more about DST issues can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22602742)).

Comment: Note however that adding 24 hours and adding a day are not the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(
    "2018-01-01 00:00:40.554".replace( " " , "T" )
).plusMinutes( 60 )
```

> 2018-01-01T01:00:40.554

## java.time

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

### ISO 8601

Your input is nearly in the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format used by default in the *java.time* classes. To comply, replace SPACE in the middle with a `T`.

```
String input = "2018-01-01 00:00:40.554".replace( " " , "T" ) ;
```

### `LocalDateTime`

Your string input lacks an indicator of [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone) or [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset). So parse as a [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html).

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2018-01-01T00:00:40.554

### Time zone

Note that you do *not* have an actual moment, this is *not* a specific point on the timeline. This is only a vague idea about *potential* moments along a range of about 26-27 hours. To determine an actual moment, place this in the context of a time zone (or offset): `ZonedDateTime zdt = ldt.atZone( ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ) ;`.

### Date-time math

You can represent your spans of time unattached to the timeline as a `Period` for years-months-days or a `Duration` for hours-minutes-seconds.

```
Duration d24Hours = Duration.ofHours( 24 ) ;
```

> d24Hours.toString(): PT24H

```
Duration d60Minutes = Duration.ofMinutes( 60 ) ;
```

> d60Minutes.toString(): PT1H

Call the `plus` method to add those spans of time.

```
LocalDateTime ldtLater = ldt.plus( d60Minutes ) ;
```

> ldtLater.toString(): 2018-01-01T01:00:40.554

```
LocalDateTime ldtMuchLater = ldt.plus( d24Hours ) ;
```

> ldtMuchLater.toString(): 2018-01-02T00:00:40.554

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).